# Square of sum of four cards?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, estimation

> Four cards are drawn from a standard set of 52. What is the expected
>   value of the square of the sum of the cards? Does neglecting the
>   covariance result in an overestimate or underestimate? How would your answer change if you flipped over a card and it read $5$?

I assume A, J, Q, K are $1$, $11$, $12$ and $13$. Ignoring the covariance of the draws and assuming they are independent, I think it is probably safest to use linearity of expectation such that
$$\mathbb{E}[(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4)^2]=\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+...+X_4^2+2X_1X_2+...+2X_3X_4)=4^2\mathbb{E}(X)^2=$$ $$=16\times49=784.$$

I suspect the covariance should cause the result to drop, but I’m unsure how. Could someone prod me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Fix LaTex.  Hard to read now.

Comment: I believe I repaired your formatting correctly, but please check to confirm.

Comment: @lulu Yes it is, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate $E(X_1X_2)$ in the following way:
$$\
E(X_1X_2) = \sum_i\sum_jijPr(X_1=i, X_2=j)= \sum_i\sum_jijPr(X_1=i)Pr(X_2=j|X_1=i)\\
Pr(X_2=j|X_1=i)=4/51 \, \text{ } \forall \, i\neq j\\
Pr(X_2=j|X_1=i)=3/51 \, \text{ } \forall \, i=j\\
\implies E(X_1X_2) \approx 48.7255\\
E(X_2)=E(E(X_2|X_1=x))\\
E(X_2|X_1=x)=\sum_ii\times Pr(X_2=i)=\sum_{i\neq x}i\times {4\over 52} + \sum_{i= x}i\times {3\over 52}={364-x \over 51}\\
\implies E(X_2)=7\\
\implies Cov(X_1,X_2)<0
$$

Hence, Covariance causes the result to drop. Try to do it for four cards.